# Spotify Apps API - Get ID of Collaborative Playlist User

Tags: spotify

Is it possible to get the userid of the person who added a track to a collaborative playlist within the Spotify Apps API?

Answer (score 0):

In short — no. The Apps API exposes no usernames at all at this time.